# Populate a dropdown based on selection of another dropdown using servlet and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am making a page where the selection of an option in a dropdown fetches the data for another dropdown from database using an Ajax call to servlet.

This is my code.

```
<%@page import="Access.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Access</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

    #header-wrap {
        position: fixed;
        height: 92px;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: #000099;
    }

    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .form-group input
    {
    width:150px;
    }
    .details
    {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    h1 {
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
#name {
    top: 30px;
    left: 30%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<jsp:include page="/SearchController" />
<%
String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
ArrayList<String> locations=(ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("locations");
%>

<br/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-form">
    <li class="active"><a href="#give-remote" data-toggle="tab">Give Access<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li id="fromDB"><a href="#sbt-jobs" data-toggle="tab">Submitted Jobs <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Form Name -->
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="give-remote">
<br/>
<form id="remoteForm" class="form-horizontal" action="RemoteAccess" method="post">
<c:if test="${not empty Message}">
   <font color="red"><c:out value="${Message}"/></font>
</c:if>

<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Location Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                   <select class="form-control" id="location" name="location">
                    <option>Select location</option>
                     <c:forEach items="${locations}" var="locations" >
                        <option value="${locations}"> ${locations} </option>
                     </c:forEach>
                   </select>
                </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gateway Server IP</label>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
              <select class="form-control" id="svrAddr" name="svrAddr">
                <option selected="selected">Select Server</option>
              </select>
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name="svrAddr" id="svrAddr"/>-->
              </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Client Address</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clntAddr" />
                </div>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" id="submitjob" class="btn btn-default" >Submit Job</button>
        </div>
  </div>

 </form>

</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="sbt-jobs">
<jsp:include page="SbmtJobs.jsp" /> 
</form>
</div>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {

        var ip="^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
            return value.match(ip);
        }, 'Invalid IP address');

    $.validator.addMethod('IP4SvrChecker', function(value) {

            var ip="^10\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$";
                return value.match(ip);
            }, 'Invalid server IP address'
            ); 



    $('#remoteForm').validate({
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            clntAddr: {
                required: true,
                IP4Checker: true
            },
            svrAddr: {
                required: true,
                IP4SvrChecker:true
            },
            time: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });



    $('#location').change(function(event) {  
        var $location=$("select#location").val();
           $.get('SvrController',{location:$location},function(responseJson) {   
               var $select = $('#svrAddr');                           
               $select.find('option').remove(); 
               $.each(responseJson, function(index, name) {               
               $('<option>').val(index).text(name).appendTo($select);      
                });
            },'json');
        });


    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
        window.location.hash = this.hash;

    });

});

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

`

```
public class SearchController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SearchController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        try {

                ArrayList<String> locations = getLocation();
                session.setAttribute("locations", locations);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> getLocation()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con=null;
        String data;
        try {

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/remote","root","root");
             ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT concat(locnid,'/',locname,'/',locntype) FROM locations order by locnid asc");
                 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                        data = rs.getString(1);
                        list.add(data);
                }
                con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

`

```
public class SvrController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SvrController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try {

                String locnid = request.getParameter("location");
                System.out.println(locnid);
                ArrayList<String> list=null;
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                Connection con=null;
                String data;
                String locn[]=locnid.split("/");
                try {

                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/remote","root","root");
                     ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT address1,address2,altflag FROM locations WHERE locnid= ? and locntype=?");
                     ps.setString(1, locn[0]);
                     ps.setString(2, locn[2]);
                     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(3)))
                                list.add(rs.getString(2));
                            else list.add(rs.getString(1));
                        }
                        con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
                response.getWriter().write(searchList);
                //response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

However the second dropdown doesn't get populated even though SvrController receives the location id. Instead server address dropdown is received as null and is not populated. Please point out if there is any mistake

Comment: I have found the issue. It is due to ArrayList not initialized before adding it to its object